# Correlation coefficient and mean comparison

Tags: correlation, group-differences

I conducted a questionnaire survey and obtained answers for items X and Y from participants. The variables X and Y can be considered as continuous variables.The participants can be divided into two groups based on the answers for Y. I checked if the mean difference of X between the two groups is statistically significant and the answer is yes. On the other hand, I also checked the correlation coefficient between X and Y, and there is no statistically significant correlation.

Because correlation coefficients cannot detect certain types of correlations, the results above do not deny correlation between X and Y. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you intend to encompass by "correlation" in "*the results above do not deny correlation between X and Y*"; please clarify.

Comment: I meant the extent to which X and Y fluctuate together. Correlation coefficients (e.g. Pearson) show specific relationships such as linear relationships. Even if linear relationships were not detected between X and Y, other relationships may exist. Indeed, the mean comparison test detects the difference in X between two groups classified by the scores of Y. By the way, in my study, categorizing participants based on Y is theoretically meaningful. @Glen_b

Comment: You're not being specific enough, sorry. Are you talking about *monotonic* relationships or something more general?

Comment: @Glen_b, I am talking about something more general relationship. I am not sure in what situation the mean comparison test detects a difference even if correlation coefficients do not show a statistically significant relationship. If the relationship between x and y is non-monotonic, this may happen?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is in a position where an answerer can clarify several issues on having a difference in mean of X conditional on a dichotomized Y and its relationship to various kinds of dependence between them.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Glen_b

Comment: Could you show us a scatterplot?